# Spring Batch @Primary annotation overriding incorrect bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-1-a-comparison-to-xml/) to configure a Spring Batch job in Java. It makes provision for multiple data sources by using an interface that's then implemented by each data source.

This is what I have so far:

**InfrastructureConfig.java**

```
public interface InfrastructureConfiguration {
    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource();
}
```

**MySQLConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Primary
public class MySQLConfiguration implements InfrastructureConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees?useSSL=false");
        dataSource.setUsername("testing");
        dataSource.setPassword("testing");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**PostgreSQLConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class PostgreSQLConfiguration implements InfrastructureConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("testing");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**JobConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private InfrastructureConfig infrastructureConfig

    ....
}
```

By using the `@Primary` annotation for my MySQLConfig, I'd expect the mySQLConfig bean to be used. Instead, I get this:

```
2017-03-09 12:46:21.422  INFO 1496 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=mySQLConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [config/MySQLConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=postgreSQLConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [config/PostgreSQLConfiguration.class]]
```

It's overriding the mySQLConfig bean with the postgreSQLConfig bean, and thus using the postgresql driver. The question is, why?

Answer (score 1):

Place `@Primary` on the method (next to `@Bean`) instead of on the class level.

Comment: If I do that, I get an error stating "Field infrastructureConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found: mySQLConfiguration and postgreSQLConfiguration"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@Qualifier(name = "")` then to explicitly pick instance which you want.

It's also strange that you are having `@Bean` annotation on interface method. 
Also it looks bad practice for me to use autowire @Configuration classes. They are java based configs for instantiating beans.

Comment: I have tried both `@Qualifier("mySQLConfig")` and `@Resource(name="mySQLConfig")` with no luck. As for the rest, I just followed what was specified in the Spring Batch tutorial linked above. There must be something fundamentally wrong with that tutorial, then. But removing the `@Bean` annotation on the interface method has made no difference, and using the `@Inject` annotation instead of `@Autowire` was fruitless as well.

Comment: Uhm. remove @Bean annotation from all of the methods. And actually change `@Configuration` on child configs to `@Component`. I guess you have enabled component scan, right? Also I see names mismatch - InfrastructureConfig  and InfrastructureConfiguration . could it be the problem?

Comment: The name mismatch was just my mistake in the comment, sorry. I have tried what you suggested but still no luck. This is a small part of a more complex system, I think the problem might lie somewhere else. I'll update with the answer once I find it (which will hopefully be soon)

Comment: This behaves correctly, see bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13980

"@Primary does not have an effect on this overriding-by-name behavior, since it is only meant to be applied for injection point resolution: i.e. when multiple matching beans have been found in the bean definition registry but only one is to be selected for a particular injection point. This is conceptually very different from overriding bean definitions which leads to hard replacing in the registry, with the previously registered bean not available anymore."

Comment: Interesting reading about unique IDs of Spring beans. https://www.intertech.com/Blog/clarifying-spring-framework-ids-and-names/
This is not the the answer to usage of @Primary annotation, but sheds a light on how Spring behaves when multiple beans with the same identification are created.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `@Profiles` annotation.

Annotate mySql configuration class with `@Profile("mySql")` and the Postgres configuration with `@Profile("myPostgresql")`

Then annotate the `JobConfig` configuration with `@ActiveProfiles("mySql")`. This way `JobConfig` should ignore the postgres configuration.

Say you use MySQL in test, you could annotate the test class with `@ActiveProfiles("mySql")`

[Spring Profiles documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-java)

Example from the documentation:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean("dataSource")
  @Profile("development") 
  public DataSource standaloneDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql")
        .build();
  }

  @Bean("dataSource")
  @Profile("production") 
  public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws Exception {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource");
  }
}
```